# How to update thumbnail in Azure Video Indexer?

Tags: azure-video-indexer

Is there a way to update the thumbnail for a video in Azure Video Indexer? It looks like it randomly assigns a default thumbnail for the video that is uploaded - Looking for a way to update it either from Video Indexer UI or via an API.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the thumbnail you see in the right pane (in the character list) is called "best face" thumbnail, there is no API in which you can change the thumbnail to a different one.

if you rename the character you will be able to see all the thumbnails that is related to this character under customization page in people tab [VideoIndexer Customization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcvbA.jpg)

there you can delete thumbnail of the character (but even this will not change the "best face")